# (Linux Mint) MonoDevelop VB.net error: “streamwriter is not declared. it may be in-accesible due to its protection level"

Tags: linux, mono

Code:

```
 Public Class Application
 Public Shared Sub Main()
 dim sw as streamwriter
 dim sr as streamreader
 End Sub
 End Class
```

All of it was written before except for those two dim lines. I always used:

sub main/endsub and module/end module

on vb.net in windows. Is that public class thing the same thing?